# Forwarding JSTL SQL Result to Servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jstl

First of all, I need to make it clear - this is for an academic project. I also feel I should say that I know this is the wrong way of doing what I need to do, however, it's the way I have to do it, so please stick to answering the question if possible rather than alternatives.

I have to display the results of an SQL query either in JSTL or through a servlet, depending on whether the browser is a phone or not. I've managed the JSTL part, and determining whether it's a phone, and I can forward to a servlet fine.

The problem is, I need to be able to access the result variable from the servlet. It's easy enough to access this from the next JSTL page, as I can set the scope to application, however I'm not sure how to go about getting access from the servlet.

I've tried:

```
request.getParameter("viewResult");
```

but this only returns a string, whereas I believe I need a

```
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result
```

object.

Does anyone know of a way to pass an object from a JSTL JSP page on to a servlet when forwarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` returns HTTP request parameters which are implicitly always `Strings` since that's just specified so in the HTTP specification.

You rather want to set it as request attribute. You can do that with `var` attribute of [`sql:query`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/query.html).

```
<sql:query dataSource="${dataSource}" var="result" scope="request">
    SELECT * FROM foo
</sql:query>
<jsp:include page="/servletURL" />
```

This way it'll be available in the servlet as follows:

```
Result result = (Result) request.getAttribute("result");
```

---

Needless to say that this is indeed not the best practice. Those tags are designed for quick prototyping, not for real world applications (Sun/Oracle's own words). You should rather be obtaining the DB result in `doGet()` or `doPost()` method of the servlet (for preprocessing resp postprocessing).

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, forgot to change that. Fixed now, and it's all working.